# WordPress blog in Subdirectory of Django site on cPanel

Tags: django, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm updating the question as I have gotten closer. What I want to achieve is to load any url that contains /blog/ with WordPress. I have moved my WordPress instance into a folder called blog (inside public_html) and changed the WordPress URL and Site Address in the database to mysite.com/blog/ with https://. It loads fine when the Django instance is not active with the below .htaccess file in public_html, and when I don't have a .htaccess file in the blog folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

After Chris's comment I managed to edit the .htaccess file to the below which allows WordPress to load but brokenly if URL contains /blog/

```
# if the Apache module mod_rewrite is enabled on the server then run the rules inside this block
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# activate the Apache mod_rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# set the base URL for relative rewrite rules. 
# specifies that the base URL for rewriting is the root directory (/).
RewriteBase /

# if url contains /blog/ then load /blog/index.php. 
# [L] indicates that this is the last rule to be processed if url contains /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /blog/
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]

# Serve other requests with Python
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / [L]
</IfModule>

# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/usr/mysite.com"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerPython "/home/usr/virtualenv/mysite.com/3.11/bin/python"
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END

# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION BEGIN
<IfModule Litespeed>
SetEnv DEBUG False
etc...
</IfModule>
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION END
```

The last piece of the puzzle which im struggling with is to load WordPress without broken assets (images, stylesheet, etc). Also wp-admin is not accessible due to "too many redirects". To do this I think I need to add a .htaccess file within the /blog/ folder to correct the broken links but I can't figure out what to add to get it working. At the moment the furthest I've gotten is to comment out everything otherwise the /blog/* url stops working.

Comment: For mod rewrite, conditions stack until a rule is encountered. In your first block you’ve got “if the URL starts with blog and no directory or file exists, route it to the blog/index.php file”. This is the basis for WordPress and most modern CMSs. In your second block, you have something similar, but there’s a rule in the middle which rests the condition stack for the next set.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks! That really helped me fix the htaccess in the root directory but another one seems to be needed inside the /blog/ directory in order for it to work correctly. I have updated the question with the progress i've made.